# Find the Maclaurin polynomial of degree $5$ for $f(x) = x\cos(x^2)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm pretty lost on this one. Can someone help me out?

Find the Maclaurin polynomial of degree $5$ for f(x) = $x\cos(x^2)$.

Comment: you can format your questions using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) is also worth a read

Comment: Thank you for the help, though I'm still scratching my head on how to figure this question out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you taken the first 5 derivatives of the function? If so, what did you get? Do you know the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)$?

Comment: Find the series for $g(x)=\cos x$.  Then replace $x$ by $x^2$ and multiply by $x$.

Comment: I tried taking the first 5 derivatives and ended up with something along the lines of "0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -60" when I replaced x with 0.

Answer (score 1):

If  $f(x)$ is a power series,the sum of its terms up to and including the term of degree $n$ is the  Maclaurin polynomial of $f(x)$ of degree $n.$
$$x\cos(x^2)=x(1-\frac{1}{2!}(x^2)^2+...))$$
$$=x-\frac{1}{2}x^5+...$$. The Maclaurin polynomial of degree 5 is $x-\frac{1}{2}x^5.$

Answer (score 1):

Use
$$\cos(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
$$\cos(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n}}{(2n)!}$$
$$x\cos(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n+1}}{(2n)!}$$ Truncate wherever you need.